# How to use <composite-map-key> in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

As per [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-asmapindex), we can use components as key of a map using `<composite-map-key>` tag. So I tried to create a program to understand how it works but got stuck on how to create the mapping file.

I have declared a pojo classes for:

`Person.java`

```
public class Person {
    private java.util.Date birthday;
    private Map<Name, String> someNames = new HashMap<Name,String>();
    private int id;
    // Setters & Getters   
}
```

Component class `Name.java`:

```
public class Name {
    String first;
    String last;
  // Setters & Getters    
}
```

I tried to create the mapping file but I am not sure how it should look like, here is the file which is not correct:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Person" table="test_person">
        <id name="id" column="pid" type="int">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="birthday" type="date" />
        <map name="someNames" table="test_person_names">
            <key column="person_id"></key>
            <composite-map-key class="Name">
                <key-property name="first" column="first1"></key-property>
                <key-property name="last" column="last1"></key-property>
            </composite-map-key>
            <property name="initial" column="initial1" />
        </map>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I am trying to get the session factory then i am getting an exception saying:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type
>   "map" must match
>   "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,key,(map-key|composite-map-key|map-key-many-to-many|index|composite-index|index-many-to-many|index-many-to-any),(element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,filter*)".

Can someone please help me how can we use `composite-map-key` to use a component as a key of map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
<property name="initial" column="initial1" />
```

It should be:

```
<element type="string" column="initial1" />
```

Other thing: remember to Implement `equals` & `hashCode` in `Name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can you please let me know if there is any other online material or book I can refer, as the online documentation is not clear?

Comment: There seems to be no text-book examples of `composite-map-key` in the internet so sorry, I've got nothing solid. In cases like this I usually go through the mapping rigorously and verify that it conforms to the DTD (like in this case, the problem was that `<map>` must contain `<element>` instead of `<property>`).

Comment: ok got it now on how to check these kind of issues. Thanks heikkim